# Kotlins many variety of collections is confusing

Tags: collections, kotlin

So while I was doing my game project in Kotlin, I thought why does Kotlin have so many collections? Like `list`, `set`, etc. is very confusing. I mean a `list`, `mutableList`, and a `hashMap` is good enough. In Python, there is only a `list`, `tuple`, and a `dictionary` (`hashMap`). I want to know what are the each collections are useful for and what is it used for, because I want to know all the types before I even start programming. By the way, I'm from Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131655/what-is-the-difference-between-lists-arraylists-maps-hashmaps-collections-et) to obtain more information about Java collection classes (because of [Kotlin reliant on Java code from the existing Java Class Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))).

For more information about the idea of mutable and immutable collections in Kotlin you can check [official documentation page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html).