# Newtonsoft Serialize the List of Objects

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to generate Serialized string of `List <object>` without any `[` `]`

we are doing serialization using following code

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)

[
  {
    "SessionId": "6d1ea52b-9f0c-4c32-835d-49e6db22efee",
    "ComponentName": "WebRole",
    "Message": "X"
  },
  {
    "SessionId": "6d1ea52b-9f0c-4c32-835d-49e6db22efee",
    "ComponentName": "WebRole",
    "Message": "Y"
  },
  {
    "SessionId": "6d1ea52b-9f0c-4c32-835d-49e6db22efee",
    "ComponentName": "WebRole",
    "Message": "Z"
  },
  {
    "SessionId": "6d1ea52b-9f0c-4c32-835d-49e6db22efee",
    "ComponentName": "WebRole",
    "Message": "XY"
  },
  {
    "SessionId": "6d1ea52b-9f0c-4c32-835d-49e6db22efee",
    "ComponentName": "WebRole",
    "Message": "XYZ",
    "Payload": "X>>1"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to remove above `[` and `]` , I have workaround to call `Trim('[')` and `Trim(']')` on serialize string. Is there any setting that come out of box from NewtonSoft which removes `[` and `]`, also I dont want to make use of anonymous object.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4 numbers after SessionId property are typos or they are present in your data ?

Comment: If you remove square brackets `[]` then your resultant JSON would be invalid. You can copy and paste your output json check here http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: we will not use deserialize function in C#. Instead, we will be ingesting data using some tool to insert into SQL/Data Store etc.

Comment: you would use `Substring` like => `var newStr = jsonStr.Substring(1, jsonStr.Length - 1);`

Comment: If you tell `newtonsoft` to remove square brackets from json then It replies you that **I am being programmed to produce only valid JSON, so how can I give you invalid JSON?** So my suggestion is to go with string manipulation by using `Trim` or `Substring`

Answer (score 1):

No there's no way, if `data` is a collection then JsonConvert will return a JSON array. You can as you stated modify the output string by using `Trim('[').Trim(']')` but your JSON won't be valid.

Comment: You should add suggestions as comment

Comment: @Sunil the question was "Is there a way to remove above ... ?" and my answer was no, I edit my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a List, not a Map/Dictionary, but you don't want the array behavior that comes with a List (but not a Dictionary/Map).

Get these straight and you'll find data MUCH easier to work with in many programming languages ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131714/901899