# Internally HashSet is using HashMap only but why we are going for hashSet instead of hashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, hashset

The internal implementation of HashSet
.......................................

```
public class HashSet<E>
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
   private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
   private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
   //constructors
   public HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
   }
   public HashSet(int initialCapacity) {
    map = new HashMap<>(initialCapacity);
   }
   public HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    map = new HashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
   }
   public HashSet(Collection<? usnoextends E> c) {
    map = new HashMap<>(Math.imax((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll(c);
   }
   //add method
   public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
 }
```

Internally HashSet is using HashMap only and performance-wise  HashMap is faster than HashSet
So why we are not using HashMap directly instead of going for HashSet.

Comment: Well there are scenarios where you might want to be working with a set rather than a hashmap.  What is your exact question?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance-wise HashMap is faster than HashSet"?

Answer (score 3):

Because `HashSet` is another type of collection - focused on the single object rather than pair of items. To make `HashMap` work like `HashSet` we would need to provide everywhere some artificial `value` object like

```
HashMap<MyItem, Object> set;
```

and then instead of e.g. `set.add(new MyItem())` use something like `set.put(new MyItem(), null)` what makes no sense and can cause serious issues (when type of `Object` will be changed, when you will need to serialize etc)

Moreover internal implementation is nothing you should take care of - it can change in the next Java version (probably won't) and some another mechanism will be used underneath. The most important is `Set` interface and the fact `HashSet` is implementing this

[What is the difference between Lists, ArrayLists, Maps, Hashmaps, Collections etc..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131655/what-is-the-difference-between-lists-arraylists-maps-hashmaps-collections-et)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @m.antkowicz, though it internally uses HashMap, there is no guarantee.

Another major reason:

1. Generally in large projects, interfaces are defined independent of implementations.
2. If a business interface expects Set (or even Collection), it will define it as `Set`(or `Collection`)
3. The interface does not care about the underlying implementations(they assume the expected behavior will be maintained)
4. Any business concrete implementation of the interface should declare the method signature exactly(to override)
5. So, they also will use `Set`(or `Collection`)

Also, different implementations of `Set` use different `Map`

1. `ConcurrentSkipListSet` uses `ConcurrentNavigableMap`
2. `HashSet` uses `HashMap`

So, this is difficult to use exactly in interface contracts.